# Using Pandas, How to make each item in a List populate each cell in a pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

Title: Using Pandas, how to make each item in a List (list is defined as a variable) populate each cell in a column.

Great community here, and thanks for looking at this. I researched this problem a lot, but maybe I'm too much an amateur. Any help is much appreciated.

Code:

```
df = pd.read_excel('OriginalSpreadsheet.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')

list(set(df.COSIGNER))
list(df['COSIGNER'].unique())

x = list(df['COSIGNER'].unique())

df1 = pd.DataFrame()
df1['Unique'] = [x]

twodf = pd.concat([df, df1], ignore_index=True)
```

Output: 
- Created a column titled Unique
- Placed the list/dataframe `df1` into the column titled 'Unique'

Problem:
- The list/dataframe `df1` values were all placed into the last cell of the excel spreadsheet. How can I place each item in the list into individual cells in the columns 'Unique' that I created. Current and ideal output is in the image:
[image: 1]

Answer (score 2):

Figured out the Answer:

```
df = pd.read_excel('OriginalSpreadsheet.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')

list(set(df.COSIGNER))
list(df['COSIGNER'].unique())

x = list(df['COSIGNER'].unique())
```

---

```
# ORIGINAL CODE THAT DIDN'T WORK: 
#df1 = pd.DataFrame()
#df1['Unique'] = [x]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=['unique'])
```

---

```
# ORIGINAL CODE THAT DIDN'T WORK: 
#twodf = pd.concat([df, df1], ignore_index=True)

twodf = pd.concat([df, df1], axis=1)
```